# Socket.io emit response to selected connections

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, frontend, eventemitter

I have 2  type of users conencted to `Socket`, 1. Admin, and 2. User

I want to `emit` some `event` only to admin `connections`. While conencting to socket im sending `query` as below

```
var connectionOptions =  {
    "force new connection" : false,
    "reconnection": true,
    "reconnectionDelay": 2000,
    "reconnectionDelayMax" : 60000,
    "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity",
    "timeout" : 10000,
    "transports" : ["websocket"],
    "query": {
        "is_admin": true,
        "token": TOKEN,
    }
  }

var socket = require('socket.io-client')(process.env.SOCKET, connectionOptions);
```

Server side, I have a function to check admin and user tokens, and conenction them to the `Socket`.

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
    let query = socket.handshake.query;
    if(query.is_admin) someAdminAuth(query.token);
    else someUserAuth(query.token)
}).on('connection', (socket) => {

});

module.exports.sendSocket = (event_name, data) => {
    let str = io.sockets.query;
    console.log(str, "str")
    io.sockets.emit(event_name, data);
}
```

Now, Somewhere I'll be Emitting an event `NOTIFY_ADMIN` function and all the `connections` will get the event. But I don't want to notify all the `connections`. I want to Push the `event` only to the user who have `is_admin: true`. how can i do that?

I can `listen` to the event in the `frontend`, instead of that if I can only psh the message to specific conenction category would be better.

Comment: Well, you'll have to show us where you're trying to emit to the single socket.  If it's inside of `someAdminAuth()` or `someUserAuth()`, then just pass the `socket` to them so they can do `socket.emit()`.  There has to be a context for how you know which socket you want to send to and you have to use that context to get the right `socket` object.  There are various ways to do that, but it all depends upon what your context is and how YOU identify what socket you want to send to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I can see here, you don't have access to some query params in server socket.io object. You need to group your users and there are 3 options:

1. Namespace
2. Room
3. Dead simple array of users socket ids who has admin token

You can read about specific details each or them and choose what fit your case more.

After that, you can emit any event to specific room, namespace or number of ids that related to admins!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I created the room and It worked fine as expected.